# jQuery div width animation doesn't animate smoothly

Tags: jquery, css-float, jquery-animate

I'm working on a splash page for a website for a client.

The idea is that the blue bar will grow over the hovered text and the text will change color. I have the basic elements in place, but for some reason the bar behaves very glitchily and won't stay in place. It seems to be a result of the float, but I can't see how to get the bar to grow in width to the left otherwise.

here is my jQuery code

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.work_link').hover(
function () {
    $('.work_link').stop(true,false).animate({color:'#ffffff'}, 500);
        $('#splash_bar_mono').stop(true, false).animate({width:'350px'}, 500).css({'float':'right'});
        //mouseover
},
function () {
$('.work_link').stop(true, false).animate({color:'#000'}, 500);
$('#splash_bar_mono').stop(true, false).animate({width:'10px'}, 500);//mouseout
});
$('.play_link').hover(
function () {
    $('.play_link').stop(true, false).animate({color:'#ffffff'}, 500);
    $('#splash_bar_mono').animate({width:'325px'}, 500).css({'float':'left'});//mouseover
},
function () {
    $('.play_link').stop(true, false).animate({color:'#000'}, 500);//mouseout
    $('#splash_bar_mono').stop(true, false).animate({width:'10px'}, 500);
});
});
```

Here is the website HTML

```
   <body id="splash">
<div id="splash_center">
        <div style="z-index:200;" id="splash_work"><a  style="z-index:200;" class="work_link" href="#">WORK</a></div>
        <div style="z-index:200;"id="splash_play"><a style="z-index:200;" class="play_link" href="#">PLAY</a></div>
    <div id="splash_bars">
        <div style="z-index:-200;" id="splash_bar_mono"></div>          
    </div>

</div>
  <div id="splash_graphic"></div>


</body>      
</html>
```

http://fefifofilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why you are having issues is by using the other div to slide underneath of it. That is causing your hover methods to be toggled while the slide is underneath.

I have been able to fix this using a slightly different approach. Instead of animating a different bar with a background color. I have opted to using a background gradient on the splash_work and splash_play.

Here is the jsFiddle with an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/9H4JU/

Also you can download the gradient i used from http://sexyselect.net/blog/image.axd?picture=2012%2f5%2fgrad.png

How this helps...

Comment: Wow that is a lot smoother. I think that is a lot better and simpler solution. I didn't know you could animate the background position like that. Genius.

Comment: That worked great, but it is broken in Firefox...I think it has something to do with firefox not supporting the background-position-x feature. Any thoughts?